# Does file exist in current Folder using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, file-exists, database-cursor

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchFile_InAllDirectories 
     @SearchFile VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE @BasePath VARCHAR(1000),
        @Path VARCHAR(1000),
        @FullPath VARCHAR(2000),
        @Id INT;

SET @SearchFile = 'test2019.txt'

CREATE TABLE tmp_BasePath 
(
    basePath VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO tmp_BasePath (basePath) 
VALUES ('\\Path1'), ('\\Path1\Images_5'),
        ('\\Path3\Images_4'), ('\\basketballfolder\2017_Images'),
        ('\\basketballfolder\2017_Images')

CREATE TABLE tmp_DirectoryTree 
(
     id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
     subdirectory VARCHAR(512),
     depth INT,
     isfile BIT,
     fullpath VARCHAR(500)
);

DECLARE basePath_results CURSOR FOR
    SELECT bp.basePath

OPEN basePath_results

FETCH NEXT FROM basePath_results into @BasePath

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tmp_DirectoryTree (subdirectory, depth, isfile)
        EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree @BasePath, 0, 1;

    FETCH NEXT FROM basePath_results INTO @Basepath
END

CLOSE basePath_results;
DEALLOCATE basePath_results;

END
```

I am creating a stored procedure that will check to see if the file passed in as a parameter, is located in one of the hard coded folders.

For example, if I pass in a file named "test2019.txt", the stored procedure should then check to see if that file exist in the folder. If yes, return true and return file path.

So essentially I just want to check if a file exist in current directory if yes give me back the full path.

Right now I am able to use a cursor to dynamically get the folder paths. Now just need a way to check to see if the file exist in the folder path, and return full path.

Please see code. I hope this makes sense. Thanks for help.

I am using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Three letters....[CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-clr-functions?view=sql-server-2017). Doing this in straight t-sql is painful and slow.

Comment: Why do this is SQL Server in the first place? Surely doing so in the application would be a far easier, and better, way to do this. XY Problem?

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. CLR sounds like a good idea. and i cannot build it in the application due to owners request.

Comment: Look into xp_fileexist

Comment: i was looking for a different solution than xp_fileexist, although it does work, was looking for something a little more dynamic. If not i will use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have another solution for you
it uses the xp_cmdshell command to retrieve and store all the files with their full pathes inside a given folder

### Please replace "répertoire de" by the English translation "folder of ", I am using a French Edition of Windows

```
**

--Kamel Gazzah
    --19/03/2019
    --Script to retrieve all the files in a a folder, inside all the sub 
     directoris

declare @folder as varchar(100)
-----------------------------------------
set @folder='d:\'
-----------------------------------------
declare @script as varchar(2000)
set @script='exec master..xp_cmdshell "dir '+@folder+'  /N /s"'
declare @mytab as table(id int identity(1,1),date_time datetime,folder int,filename varchar(1000),parent_folder varchar(200))
insert into @mytab(filename) exec(@script)
update @mytab set date_time= substring(filename,1,18) where date_time is null and isdate(substring(filename,1,18))=1
update @mytab set folder=1 where filename like '%répertoire de%' and folder is null
update @mytab set folder=0 where filename not like '%<DIR>%' and folder is null and date_time is not null
update @mytab set filename=replace(filename,'répertoire de ','') where folder=1
delete from @mytab where folder is null
update @mytab set parent_folder=t2.filename
--select t1.id,t1.folder,t1.filename,t2.filename
 from @mytab t1
outer apply (select top 1 filename from @mytab where id<t1.id  and folder=1 order by id desc) t2
where t1.folder=0
UPDATE @mytab SET FILENAME=substring(filename,37,len(filename)) WHERE FOLDER=0 
select id,replace(replace(parent_folder,'\',''),':',':\')+'\'+filename [Fullpath] from @mytab where folder=0
```

**

Comment: thanks this is working. Had to tweak the 'like' to accept a variable, but it works great. thanks for the help!